# Alt-tab within VNC and back to my desktop

Tags: linux, windows, desktop-environments, vnc-viewer

My local desktop is Windows 7, and my remote Linux machine is Ubuntu + Gnome. I access my linux machine via VNCViewer.

When I'm working on my desktop, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between my desktop programs.

I've enabled `Pass special keys directly to VNC Server` in my VNCViewer. Special keys is pretty important in Linux and it'd be strange if I don't have them.

The problem is that when I'm in VNCViewer, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches between programs within my Linux machine. If I want to switch back out to a desktop program (say I want to go to email, or a browser), there's no keyboard shortcut to do that. I need to manually click on any desktop programs to get myself out of VNC, and then do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. This is very inefficient.

Any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: you are going to have to make up your mind and accept a standard approach to how you want VNC to handle special keymaps. you can't have it mostly one way and a little the other. even if you changed the local `alt+tab` to `alt+\`` or somthing else, VNC will still send the keypress to the remote box.

Comment: i was thinking other people might have faced this problem before and might have a good solution.